# prolog - Generating dates between dates

Tags: date, prolog, between

I need to generate all dates between two given dates.

My predicate **date_between(DateLow, DateHigh, X)** works correctly:

```
?- date_between(date(2020,2,15), date(2020,2,25), X).
X = date(2020, 2, 15) ;
X = date(2020, 2, 16) ;
....
X = date(2020, 2, 25) .
```

But I think predicate is too clumsy. Is there another approach to do the same but more elegant?

Should I translate back and forth Date to Seconds (Stamp) and Seconds to Date?

I have to compare dates through conversion in seconds?

You can see my code:

```
date_between(DateLow, DateHigh, DateLow) :-
  datestd_stamp(DateLow, StampLow),
  datestd_stamp(DateHigh, StampHigh),
  StampLow =< StampHigh.

date_between(DateLow, DateHigh, X) :-
  datestd_stamp(DateLow, StampLow),
  datestd_stamp(DateHigh, StampHigh),
  StampLow < StampHigh,
  DateLow = date(Y,M,D),
  Dnxt is D + 1,
  date_time_stamp(date(Y,M,Dnxt,0,0,0,0,-,-), StampNext),
  stamp_date_time(StampNext, Dat, 0),
  date_time_value(date, Dat, DateNxt),
  date_between(DateNxt, DateHigh, X).

datestd_stamp(Data, Stamp) :-
  Data = date(Y,M,D),
  date_time_stamp(date(Y,M,D,0,0,0,0,-,-), StampTmp),
  round(StampTmp, Stamp).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to improve the predicate. The execution time has definitely been reduced.

The predicate has become simpler and faster.

Old version:

```
?- time((bagof(X, (date_between(date(2020,1,1), date(2100,12,31), X)), Ls))).
% 680,466 inferences, 0.149 CPU in 0.149 seconds (100% CPU, 4563901 Lips)
Ls = [date(2020, 1, 1), date(2020, 1, 2), date(2020, 1, 3),
```

New version:

```
?- time((bagof(X, (date_between2(date(2020,1,1), date(2100,12,31), X)), Ls))).
% 207,106 inferences, 0.066 CPU in 0.066 seconds (100% CPU, 3157900 Lips)
Ls = [date(2020, 1, 1), date(2020, 1, 2), date(2020, 1, 3),
```

You can see new version of predicate:

```
date_between2(DateLow, DateHigh, DateLow) :-
  DateLow @=< DateHigh.

date_between2(DateLow, DateHigh, X) :-
  DateLow @< DateHigh,
  DateLow = date(Y,M,D),
  Dnxt is D + 1,
  date_time_stamp(date(Y,M,Dnxt,0,0,0,0,-,-), StampNext),
  stamp_date_time(StampNext, Dat, 0),
  date_time_value(date, Dat, DateNxt),
  date_between2(DateNxt, DateHigh, X).
```